# Scale out of RAM in a cluster architecture?

Tags: node.js, performance, caching, redis, ram

In an application, there is a main server (M). This server sends a request to server cluster (C), where the master (CM) receives the request and proceeds to aggregate data from RAMs of slaves CS1, CS2, CS3 ....

**Question** - If I want CS1, CS2, CS3 .... to have a shared memory space so that I can use Redis API normally, how can this scale out of RAM be achieved in CS(n) set? How hard is this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) is a possible solution, if data is such that it can be stored in a RAM based db.